# Smartcard authentication on CentOS

Tags: centos, login, authentication, smartcard

I tried to implement a smart card authentication in a Samba4 domain (Samba AD).
Currently I have two domain controllers (CentOS), a file server and several clients (CentOS and Windows). In regards to the smart card, I have a "Téo by Xiring" card reader and a "Gemalto IDPrime 510 (.Net V3)" card.
I also have the appropriate drivers and I can authenticate with a smart card on Windows but It's not possible on CentOS.

The smart card reader and the card seem recognized by CentOS (present in lsusb -v and inserting the card launches "Smart Card Manager" but informs that the certificate isn't known and the card not formatted). However using the module *libgtop11dotnet* I can read the certificate and even connect (with the corresponding PIN) using pkcs11-tool (but I must specify the module). In spite of all this, it is impossible for me to login on CentOS using the smart card. Even by forcing the use of the smart card to logon, nothing happens. Is there a special modification to be on pam_pkcs11 or Kerberos to specify which module to use or to link the user certificate with the domain user ?

All commands like : opensc-tool -n, pklogin_finder debug, pkcs11_inspect debug et pkcs11_listcerts debug return an error.

**Commands :**

```
[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/local/lib/libgtop11dotnet.so -l -O
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to ".NET #514CA4DC28D2DF4D".
Please enter User PIN:
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      a1b062f9-7bfd-af90-3d7e-61cfd2105a0a
  ID:         a1b062f97bfdaf903d7e61cfd2105a0a145fec47
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      a1b062f9-7bfd-af90-3d7e-61cfd2105a0a
  ID:         a1b062f97bfdaf903d7e61cfd2105a0a145fec47
  Usage:      encrypt, verify
Private Key Object; RSA
  label:      a1b062f9-7bfd-af90-3d7e-61cfd2105a0a
  ID:         a1b062f97bfdaf903d7e61cfd2105a0a145fec47
  Usage:      decrypt, sign


[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ modutil -list -dbdir /etc/pki/nssdb
Listing of PKCS #11 Modules
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1. NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
         slots: 2 slots attached
        status: loaded

         slot: NSS Internal Cryptographic Services
        token: NSS Generic Crypto Services

         slot: NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services
        token: NSS Certificate DB

  2. libgtop11dotnet
        library name: /usr/local/lib/libgtop11dotnet.so
         slots: 5 slots attached
        status: loaded

         slot: XIRING Teo 00 00
        token: .NET #514CA4DC28D2DF4D

         slot: empty
        token:

         slot: empty
        token:

         slot: empty
        token:

         slot: empty
        token:
-----------------------------------------------------------


[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ opensc-tool -l
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             XIRING Teo 00 00


[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.25 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.8
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: XIRING Teo 00 00

Tue Sep 25 07:18:18 2018
Reader 0: XIRING Teo 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, Shared Mode,
  ATR: 3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64

ATR: 3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 16, Y(1): 0001, K: 6 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 96 --> Fi=512, Di=32, 16 cycles/ETU
    250000 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 312500 bits/s
+ Historical bytes: 41 73 74 72 69 64
  Category indicator byte: 41 (proprietary format)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64
        Gemalto .NET v2.0


[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ opensc-tool -n
Using reader with a card: XIRING Teo 00 00
Unsupported card


[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ pkcs11_listcerts debug
DEBUG:pam_config.c:238: Using config file /etc/pam_pkcs11/pam_pkcs11.conf
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:182: Initializing NSS ...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:192: Initializing NSS ... database=/etc/pki/nssdb
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:210: ...  NSS Complete
DEBUG:pkcs11_listcerts.c:69: loading pkcs #11 module...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:235: Looking up module in list
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:238: modList = 0x21a49c0 next = 0x21bf3c0

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:239: dllName= <null>

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:238: modList = 0x21bf3c0 next = 0x0

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:239: dllName= libgtop11dotnet.so

DEBUG:pkcs11_listcerts.c:77: initialising pkcs #11 module...
DEBUG:pkcs11_listcerts.c:94: no token available
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does pkcs11-tool show the certificates _without_ the `-l` option?

Comment: Yep, from the moment I specify the module this command works fine. I just don't have the last part :
`[MYDOMAIN\administrator@Client1 ~]$ pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/local/lib/libgtop11dotnet.so -O
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      a1b062f9-7bfd-af90-3d7e-61cfd2105a0a
  ID:         a1b062f97bfdaf903d7e61cfd2105a0a145fec47
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      a1b062f9-7bfd-af90-3d7e-61cfd2105a0a
  ID:         a1b062f97bfdaf903d7e61cfd2105a0a145fec47
  Usage:      encrypt, verify `

Comment: pam_pkcs11 is used to log into the local machine. You may need to use a pam_krrb5. Kerberos uses PKINT to authenticate using smartcard to the domain controller (KDC)

Comment: Have you looked at; https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-kerberos-pam.html

Comment: To see what is going on with the PKCS#11 you can use the [OpenSC SPY](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-OpenSC) It is a PKCS#11 module that loads another PKCS#11 module.

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html  may be helpfull. Look for the PKINIT section.  The client machine and the KDC need to trust each others CA's.   You can use the pkcs11-tool --test --login to test if the card can sign something.     https://github.com/AbigailBuccaneer/libgtop11dotnet   might help.   The "Smart Card Manager" might be getting in the way.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your help.
I already have OpenSC SPY but all commands exept pkcs11-tool (when I specify the module : libgtop11dotnet) return an error. The command detects that the card is inserted but returns : "Failed to connect to card : Card is invalid of cannot be handled".
In regards to PKINIT I also have problems. With the modification of krb5.conf I can connect with a smart card on kerberos. When I do a "kinit" the PIN is expected and if I put the right pin it works.

Comment: But, even after editing pam.d files (like here : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/krb-smart-cards but by changing the module by libgtop11dotnet.so) I still can't connect to a session with smart card, nothing happends when I put the card on lock screen.
I think I'm on the right way but I'm blocked.

Comment: I also tried the command "pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/local/lib/libgtop11dotnet.so --test --login" but returns :

`Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to ".NET #514CA4DC28D2DF4D".
Please enter User PIN:
C_SeedRandom() and C_GenerateRandom():
  seeding (C_SeedRandom) not supported
  ERR: C_GenerateRandom(buf1,0) failed: CKR_ARGUMENTS_BAD (0x7)
error: PKCS11 function C_GetMechanismList failed: rv = CKR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL (0x150)
Aborting.` @DouglasEngert